# Given $f\in R (\mathbb{T}),$ Prove $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty|\hat f(n)|= \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, periodic-functions

> Let $f\in R (\mathbb{T})$ be a continuous function in every $x\neq x_0$ with period $2\pi$.
>
> Suppose that at $x_0,$ the one-sided limits exist and different one from the other.
>
> **Prove:** $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty|\hat f(n)|=\infty$

First, I tried to work with *Bessel's inequality*, but couldn't really get far.

Second, I tried to work with *Fejér's theorem*, but again, got stuck.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Assume the sum is finite and prove that $f$ must be continuous also at $x_0$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I couldn't make much progress. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Look at $\sum_n \hat{f} (n) e^{inx}$. Show that it equals $f(x)$ and is continuous.

Comment: You mean show the Fourier series converges to $f?$ I know it's true in $L_2$, but how is that enough? And how could I prove it's continuous?

Comment: When the above-mentioned sum is finite the Fourier series is a uniformly convergent sum of continuous functions